# reading struct -- uint32 does not name a type

Tags: c++, g++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <zlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc <2){        exit(0);}

    //map<int, int> myMap;
    struct last_touch
    {
        vector<uint64> baz;
        uint32 foo;
        uint32 bar;
    }myLastTouch;

    gzFile m_fHandle;
    m_fHandle = gzopen(argv[1], "rb");
    while(!gzeof(m_fHandle))
    {

        gzread(m_fHandle,&myLastTouch, sizeof(last_touch));

        vector<uint64>::size_type sz =  myLastTouch.baz.size();
        cout<<"size \t"<<sz<<endl; 

    }   
        gzclose(m_fHandle);
}
```

I'm trying to read a struct from a compressed file.
and I compile it using `g++ -lz test.cpp`

```
In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:15: error: ‘uint64’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:15: error: template argument 1 is invalid
test.cpp:15: error: template argument 2 is invalid
test.cpp:16: error: ‘uint32’ does not name a type
test.cpp:17: error: ‘uint32’ does not name a type
test.cpp:27: error: ‘uint64’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
test.cpp:27: error: template argument 1 is invalid
test.cpp:27: error: template argument 2 is invalid
test.cpp:27: error: expected initializer before ‘sz’
```

These are the following errors I get. I think uint32 is because of `<stdint.h>`and therefore i included it.

Is there somethign else that i'm missing

Comment: Try `uint32_t`, [all the integer types in `cstdint` end in `_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint).

Comment: @VioletGiraffe The fixed-width types are from C++11. I missed the missing `_t`, though (this is what I get for being on SO while tired), so I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those types should be with `_t` postfix: uint64_t